# Rails with carrier_wave and nested form - how to save nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model User, which embeds photos (used with carrier_wave_direct). In the photo.rb model, I added a field description.
Here is the photo.rb (carrier_wave_direct):

```
class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :user

  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
  field :file, type: String
  field :description, type: String
end
```

Here is the user.rb:

```
class User
   ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => proc {|attributes| attributes['file'].blank?}
  ...
end
```

Here is the users_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @user = users.build(user_params)
  if @user.save
    @user.photos.each do |photo|
      unless photo.file.file == nil
        photo.save!
      end  
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  @user.photos.each do |photo|
    unless photo.file.file == nil
      photo.save!
    end  
  end
...
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :photos_attributes => [:id, :description, :file, :_destroy]
  )
end
```

I can see in the console that the startup params have the field description with the correct input from the form, but i can't save it. The photo is well saved though.
The form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo_f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'photo_fields', locals: { f: photo_f } %>
  <%= link_to_add_association raw('<i class="fi-plus">&nbsp; add a photo</i>'), f, :photos %>
<% end %>
```

in the partial nested-fields:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <% if f.object.file.to_s.empty? %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, label: "Upload a photo." %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag f.object.file %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: false, as: :text %>
</div>
```

I really don't know how to save the description field to the model, it is passed in the params and I don't see any error message in the console. In the show view, if I do a .inspect on user, the description field is nil (as it can not save)

Comment: I sure it happening of this `attributes['file'].blank?` in model because when you display image on the page using `image_tag f.object.file ` their is no file in params when you have image in there try changing `attributes['file'].blank?` with `(attributes['file'] || attributes['description']).blank?` and hope you  empty validation in respective model

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you so much. Would I need to make this kind of check for each field, even if this field is not mandatory ?